# jQuery to MooTools

Tags: jquery, mootools

What is best approach for converting following jQuery code to MooTools code?

```
$('.some_element a').each(function(){
  var arr = $(this).attr('href').split('/');
  var last = arr[arr.length-1];
  $(this).prepend('<img src="'+last+'" />');
});
```

Or in plain words - I need to select all links in some element ('.some_element') and prepend images to those links where image src attribute is taken from the links href attribute (the part after the last '/' in href attribute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$$('.some_element a').each(function(el) {
    var arr = el.get('href').split('/');
    var last = arr.getLast();
    var image = Element('img', {
        src: last
    }).inject(el, 'before');
});
```

Live example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/oskar/yRdvD/

Comment: This works in your live example, but gives error on my firebug console (`el.get('href') is not a function...`). What can be the problem?

Comment: @egis - I'd guess that could occur if you have an `<a>` tag without a `href` attribute?

Comment: There is a `href` attribute in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: el.get("href") is not a function or el.get("href").split is not a function? if the former, it implies the element is not extended to have the mootools methods, you can add this line at the top: `document.id(el);` - which will ensure the element is extended first.

Comment: btw, +1 for oskar. @egis: make sure you're on mootools ver1.2+ else `.get` is `.getProperty` instead on 1.1x

Comment: As this answer led me to my problems solution - I accepted it. And thanks for all the comments, I'll take one more look at this piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$$('.some_element a').each(function(anchor){
    new Element('img[src="' + anchor.get('href').split('/').getLast() + '"]').inject(anchor, 'top');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example and exactly as I needed (answering my own question, hehe):

```
$$('.some_element a').each(function(el) {
  var arr = el.getAttributeNode('href').nodeValue.split('/');
  var last = arr.getLast();
  var image = new Element('img', {src : last});
  image.inject(el, 'top');
});
```

Comment: if it were the correct answer :) having said that, oskar's answer _is_ the correct mootools syntax, given that you have not supplied any markup to run it with or specified which version of mootools you use. if you use 1.12 then `.get` will not work - use `.getProperty()` instead. either way, steer clear of the `getAttributeNode` solution, imo.

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll be more specific. I'm not sure which version it is, it's part of the Joomla :) Oskars answer and this link (http://www.garrickcheung.com/javascript/form-property-setget-error-with-mootools-in-internet-explorer/) gave me the solution to my problem. getProperty() is mentioned in given article. Is it really bad?

Comment: joomla by default is 1.12 - only the latest versions allow for 1.2 being used. getProperty is not bad, it's the right way to do it in mootools 1.12, that's all. .get only got introduced in mootools 1.2 for the first time.

Comment: Sorry, i've meant `getAttributeNode` - why it's bad?